# How to maximize the number of concurrent request/connections on IIS 8 (Windows 8)?

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-services, iis-8

Recently i am building a simulator that will send request say 10 request from an IP at a time to a asp.net web service which is hosted on IIS. for this I have to change some configuration in machine.config of system and web.config of web service. regarding this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23306/10-ASP-NET-Performance-and-Scalability-Secrets)

This configuration works fine in IIS 7 (windows 7) but doesn't works in IIS8 (Windows 8).

N:B: IIS 8 works fine when I send only max 3 concurrent request from an IP.

I search a lot in Google but did not able to find anything.
Is there any other thing I have to configure for IIS8?

Answer (score 0):

Afraid that you'll need windows 8 professional or enterprise for 10 concurrent requests.
check this link out: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit.aspx